# Having issues loading sound in Java from a resource. Any ideas?

Tags: java, multithreading, audio

I've been working on a top-down 2D game for my A-Level computing projected, and my client decided he would like a sound to be played when the game starts. My issue is i've created a class called Sound, that implements runnable (see below). In this class is my audio code. I've made an instance of the class in my main Game class, and it calls `sound.playSound(path)` when the Enum state is at `START` (start screen). I appear to get no sound at all. The code is below.

Thanks for your help.

Sound class:

```
package com.ritcat14.GotYourSix.util;

import java.net.URL;

import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;

public class Sound implements Runnable {

    private String path;

    public Sound() {
    }

    public void playSound(String path){
        this.path = path;
        Thread t = new Thread();
        t.start();
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            URL defaultSound = this.getClass().getResource(path);
            AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(defaultSound);
            Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
            clip.open(audioInputStream);
            clip.start();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: @azurefrog the error doesn't appear if i dont create an instance of the sound class, so the error is in sound

Comment: We need to see the `Game` class, that is where the NPE is according to your stack trace. There's no way we could know what's going on without seeing it.

Comment: @azurefrog added game class code. Also, i know what a null pointer exception is, this question has no relevence to that question. It isn't a case of wether i know what it is, it is a case of the fact its being caused by a completely different thread and i dont know WHY, not WHAT.

Comment: @azurefrog the `getGraphics()`method wasnt being used, so i removed it. There is now no error, but there is no sound

Comment: please show us what you put in the `path`

Comment: If you load the file from path with an audio player, the sound does play?

Comment: The NPE and the path are red-herrings.  He didn't pass `this` to the new Thread, so it just no-ops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a new `Thread` in your `playSound()` method, you aren't giving it a `Runnable` to run.  This means that when you `start()` it, nothing happens.

If you take a look at what `start()` does in the [Thread API doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html), you'll see that it:

> Causes this thread to begin execution; the Java Virtual Machine calls the run method of this thread.

And the `run()` method says:

> If this thread was constructed using a separate Runnable run object, then that Runnable object's run method is called; **otherwise, this method does nothing and returns.**

(emphasis mine)

Try giving `t` a reference to `this`, so that it'll run your `Sound`'s `run()` method:

```
public void playSound(String path){
    this.path = path;
    Thread t = new Thread(this);
    t.start();
}
```